# WSAWaitForMultipleEvents and NetworkEvents

Tags: c++, networking

I'm trying to get FD_CLOSE event (c++) by WSAWaitForMulipleObjects. in the WSASelectEvent I've set only the FD_CLOSE. however, the wait return, and the network enumaration also return 0, but NetworkEvents return 0 from the enumaration so I can't see FD_CLOSE in it.

Any help?

thanks.

```
void EventThread(void* obj)
{

    WSANETWORKEVENTS NetworkEvents;

    WSAEVENT EventArray[WSA_MAXIMUM_WAIT_EVENTS];
    DWORD EventTotal = 0; 
    EventArray[EventTotal] = WSACreateEvent();
    EventTotal++;
    int res;
    int index;
    if(WSAEventSelect(_socket, EventArray[EventTotal - 1], FD_CLOSE)==SOCKET_ERROR)
        Logger::GetInstance() << "WSAEventSelect failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

    bool bResult;
    while(true)
    {
        if((index = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(EventTotal, EventArray, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE))==WSA_WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            Logger::GetInstance() << "WSAWaitForMultipleEvents failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }


         if ((index != WSA_WAIT_FAILED) && (index != WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT)) {
            res = WSAEnumNetworkEvents(_socket, EventArray[index - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0], &NetworkEvents) ;

            if(NetworkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE)
            {
                if(NetworkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT] !=0)
                {
                    Logger::GetInstance() << "FD_CLOSE failed with error " << NetworkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT] << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger::GetInstance() << "FD_CLOSE is OK!!! " << NetworkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT] << endl;
                }
            }
         }


    }

}
```

Comment: What did you do to trigger the event? (Be as precise as possible.)

Comment: register to FD_CLOSE by WSAEventSelect and then WSAWaitForMultipleEvents

Comment: Right, but what did you do to trigger the event? That's how you waited for the event, but how did you make the event occur?

Comment: I disconnect the network cable

Comment: Did you confirm that this caused the connection to terminate with 'netstat'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WinSock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540.aspx) says the following:

> The `FD_CLOSE` message is posted when a close indication is received
>   for the virtual circuit corresponding to the socket. In TCP terms,
>   this means that the `FD_CLOSE` is posted when the connection goes into
>   the `TIME_WAIT` or `CLOSE_WAIT` states. This results from the remote
>   end performing a `shutdown()` on the send side or a `closesocket()`.
>   `FD_CLOSE` should only be posted after all data is read from a socket,
>   but an application should check for remaining data upon receipt of
>   `FD_CLOSE` to avoid any possibility of losing data.
>
> Be aware that the application will only receive an `FD_CLOSE` message
>   to indicate closure of a virtual circuit, and only when all the
>   received data has been read if this is a graceful close. It will not
>   receive an `FD_READ` message to indicate this condition.
>
> ...
>
> Here is a summary of events and conditions for each asynchronous
>   notification message.
>
> ...
>
> `FD_CLOSE`: Only valid on connection-oriented sockets (for example,
>   SOCK_STREAM)
>
> 1. When `WSAAsyncSelect()` called, if socket connection has been closed.
> 2. After remote system initiated graceful close, when no data currently available to receive (Be aware that, if data has been
>      received and is waiting to be read when the remote system initiates a
>      graceful close, the `FD_CLOSE` is not delivered until all pending data
>      has been read).
> 3. After local system initiates graceful close with `shutdown()` and remote system has responded with "End of Data" notification (for
>      example, TCP FIN), when no data currently available to receive.
> 4. When remote system terminates connection (for example, sent TCP RST), and `lParam` will contain `WSAECONNRESET` error value.
>
> Note `FD_CLOSE` is not posted after `closesocket()` is called.

Pulling out the network cable does not satisfy any of those conditions.  This is actually by design, as networks are designed to handle unexpected outages so they can maintain existing connections as best as they can during short outages.  Wait a few minutes until the OS times out and see what happens.  Also, when you put the cable back in, the OS will validate pre-existing connections and then may or may not reset them at that time.